# JDBC constraint exception details

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, unique-constraint

I'm using JDBC to persist data to SQL Server and want to insert a new row into table that has a primary key, several foreign keys, and several uniqueness constraints on various columns. I am wondering how to handle constraint violations so that I can identify which fields need to be corrected (in order to report something meaningful to the user).

e.g:

table test: id (PRIMARY), fk_id (FOREIGN KEY), field1 (UNIQUE), field2 (UNIQUE)

Inserting a duplicate value in field1 OR field2 gives:

```
ErrorCode: 2627
SQLState: 23000
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint '<UNIQUE CONSTRAINT NAME>'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.test'. The duplicate key value is (<VALUE>).
```

However, this isn't enough to determine which field caused the exception (so I can tell the user, correct field1 or field2), short of parsing the error message and using the constraint name (which doesn't feel right and seems like a brittle solution).

The other way I can think of is to not rely on exceptions and instead query for any existing rows with the same value (manually checking for uniqueness before insertion). However, this requires potentially many queries in a serializable transaction (reducing concurrency). Worse, the transaction can deadlock and rollback if timing unfortunately conflicts with another transaction.

Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do without having to parse (locale specific) exception messages?
What is the 'best practice' way?